# Relative risk per increment

Tags: relative-risk

I have a study that reports summary RR and RR using an increment (e.g., 100 grams per day). In layman's terms, what does the RR using an increment mean? For example, eating chocolate overall has a RR for obesity of 1.32, while the RR for each 100 g/day increment is 1.45. I understand the first (you are 32% greater risk of becoming obese by eating chocolate) but how do I translate the second stats into a layman's term sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Without the increment you get the relative risk based on the average eating habits of the surveyed population. So if you eat a typical amount that people who eat chocolate do then your risk is 32% higher.

The problem with that is that it matters how much you eat, not just if. How much does a typical chocolate eat? How does an individual know how their consumption compares to a typical chocolate eater? 100g means nothing much without context. Most standard chocolate bars here in the UK are 50-60 g, so for a UK audience eating 2 chocolate bars a day increases the risk of obesity by around 45%.

If portion sizes in the target audience are different then the transformative needs adjusted